# jQuery text() returns null in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, text, google-chrome, string

I'm studying a strange behavior in Google Chrome when using jQuery text function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
       var t = $('#txtMessage').text();
       alert(t); //this shows nothing in Google Chrome, but works in IE9
   });
});
```

when I change `var t = $('#txtMessage').text();` to `var t = $('#txtMessage').val();` it works in Chrome.

So, what's wrong with text() function?

PS: txtMessage is a textarea

Comment: Impossible to tell without knowing what `#txtMessage` is.

Comment: What type of element is `txtMessage`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) gets the *inner* text of an element, so when getting the value it's just not an appropriate usage.
- [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) gets the value property of an input type element, and should be what you use to retrieve/set the value (this *includes* `<textarea>` elements, even though the value is between the tags).

The question isn't really "why *doesn't* `.text()` work in Chrome?", it's "why *does* `.text()` in IE?".  Stick with [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for inputs.

Comment: sure, I have being using val() by now

Comment: I've posted it to Microsoft Connect https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/618388/jquery-1-4-3-text-behavior-different-when-compared-to-chrome

Answer (score 1):

The [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function should be used to get the value of form elements like `input`, `select`, `textarea`, ...